# Android: Parse JSON as gradle argument

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

I would need to parse the JSON as a gradle parameter to supply UI tests by that data. What I am currently doing in build.gradle:

```
def getJson() {
project.getProperties().get('getJson')
}
```

and then I am calling this in gradle as:

```
buildConfigField "String", 'MYDATA', '"' + getJson + '"'
```

In the command line I am using the next call:

```
-Pjson = "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}"
```

But I am getting an error with BuildConfig:
the escaped backslash `\"` just removing the slashes at all and if I will add 1 more backslash it will remove the quote and will add 2 backslashes insted. Do you know the proper way of passing JSONString here?

Answer (score 0):

```
./gradlew -Pjson="{\\\"key1\\\": \\\"value1\\\", \\\"key2\\\": \\\"value2\\\"}"
```

`\\\"` is converted to `\\"` from CLI to gradle. And `\\"` is converted from code to String `"`.